# How to write class attribute for html element in php file?

Tags: php, html, css, magento-1.9

Cannot write class attribute in php file for html element.
Here is my code

```
echo '<div><p class="'.($value->getIsRequire() == 1) ? 'required' : ''.'">
</p> <input type="text" name="field" id="option-value" /></div>';
```

My output should be if the condition is true the class should be required otherwise the class should be empty but i got output as required text instead of input box.

**Result I got is**

[image]

Comment: Use proper parentheses.

Comment: `($value->getIsRequire() == 1) ? 'required' : ''` -> `($value->getIsRequire() == 1 ? 'required' : '')`

Comment: It shows nothing input element is not displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you should wrap it in parentheses :

```
echo '<div><p class="'.(($value->getIsRequire() == 1) ? 'required' : '').'">
</p> <input type="text" name="field" id="option-value" /></div>';
```

Comment: Great, you're welcome, feel free to mark it as the right answer